# Extracting repeated characters

Tags: r, regex, gsub, text-extraction

I am trying to extract artist and title names. However it is a bit complicated.
Here is the list;

```r
nlist <- c(
"Lil' SlimLil' Slim feat. PxMxWxPxMxWx Where Your Ward At!!",               
"I Like It (Mannie Fresh Style)I Like It (Mannie Fresh Style)Ms. Tee",
"Bella VistaBella Vista Mister Wong",
"Tom WareTom WareChina Town",                                        
"Race 'N RhythmRace 'N Rhythm Teenage Girls",                                    
"Ronald MarquisseRonald MarquisseElectro Link 7",
"PleasurePleasure Thoughts Of Old Flames",
"OM, OM, Dom Um RomaoDom Um Romao Chipero",
"HookfaceHookface4 07 181221"
)
```

Here is the pattern in the strings.

[image: PICTURE]

**Description**:

- There are three different patterns (1, 2-7, 8).
- RED: Artist (repeated),
- BLUE: Title (non-repeated),
- GREEN: Conjunction (non-rep&between artist names)

1 and 8 is very hard and I couldn't solve. But for 2 to 7 below codes solve my problem.

```r
title = str_trim(gsub('(.+?)\\1','', nlist))
artist = re.match('(.+?)\\1', nlist)[,2]
data = cbind(title,artist);data
```

And here the outputs of the above codes.

```
     title                                     artist                          
[1,] "feat. PxMxWxPxMxWx Where Your Ward At!!" "Lil' Slim"                     
[2,] "Ms. Tee"                                 "I Like It (Mannie Fresh Style)"
[3,] "Mister Wong"                             "Bella Vista"                   
[4,] "China Town"                              "Tom Ware"                      
[5,] "Teenage Girls"                           "Race 'N Rhythm"                
[6,] "Electro Link 7"                          "Ronald Marquisse"              
[7,] "Thoughts Of Old Flames"                  "Pleasure"                      
[8,] "Chipero"                                 "OM, "  
[9,] "4 07 181221"                             "Hookeface"
```

**Problem**: When there is "feat." or "," in the string that cuts the repeated sequence of the string.
**Question**: How can I extract truly the artist names like in below?

My expected result is here (Check 1 and 8);

```
     title                                     artist                          
[1,] "Where Your Ward At!!"                    "Lil' Slim feat. PxMxWx"                     
[2,] "Ms. Tee"                                 "I Like It (Mannie Fresh Style)"
[3,] "Mister Wong"                             "Bella Vista"                   
[4,] "China Town"                              "Tom Ware"                      
[5,] "Teenage Girls"                           "Race 'N Rhythm"                
[6,] "Electro Link 7"                          "Ronald Marquisse"              
[7,] "Thoughts Of Old Flames"                  "Pleasure"                      
[8,] "Chipero"                                 "OM, Dom Um Romao"                             
[9,] "4 07 181221"                             "Hookeface"
```

Thanks...

Comment: Shouldn't be `4 07 181221` the *title* and `Hookeface` the *artist* in the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following extracts what you want. I remove everything and the last repetition and store it in `title`. To get the artist I remove the length form the previously found `title` using `substr` and then remove the repetitions of the artist using `gsub` with `(.{2,})\\1`, but this will also remove repetitions in the conjunction .

```
title <- sub(".*(.{2,})\\1\\s*", "", nlist)
artist <- trimws(gsub("(.{2,})\\1", "\\1"
              , substr(nlist, 1, nchar(nlist) - nchar(title)), perl=TRUE))
cbind(title,artist)
#      title                    artist                          
# [1,] "Where Your Ward At!!"   "Lil' Slim feat. PxMxWx"        
# [2,] "Ms. Tee"                "I Like It (Mannie Fresh Style)"
# [3,] "Mister Wong"            "Bella Vista"                   
# [4,] "China Town"             "Tom Ware"                      
# [5,] "Teenage Girls"          "Race 'N Rhythm"                
# [6,] "Electro Link 7"         "Ronald Marquisse"              
# [7,] "Thoughts Of Old Flames" "Pleasure"                      
# [8,] "Chipero"                "OM, Dom Um Romao"              
# [9,] "4 07 181221"            "Hookface"
```

Another way might be:

```
x <- sub("^(.*)\\1\\s*", "", nlist)     #Remove the first repetition of artist
title <- sub(".*?(.{2,})\\1\\s*", "", x) #Remove Conjunction and repetition of Artist if there is one
artist <- trimws(gsub("(.{2,})\\1", "\\1"
              , substr(nlist, 1, nchar(nlist) - nchar(title)), perl=TRUE))
cbind(title,artist)
#      title                    artist                          
# [1,] "Where Your Ward At!!"   "Lil' Slim feat. PxMxWx"        
# [2,] "Ms. Tee"                "I Like It (Mannie Fresh Style)"
# [3,] "Mister Wong"            "Bella Vista"                   
# [4,] "China Town"             "Tom Ware"                      
# [5,] "Teenage Girls"          "Race 'N Rhythm"                
# [6,] "Electro Link 7"         "Ronald Marquisse"              
# [7,] "Thoughts Of Old Flames" "Pleasure"                      
# [8,] "Chipero"                "OM, Dom Um Romao"              
# [9,] "4 07 181221"            "Hookface"
```

Comment: Thank you @GKİ.
But at the first row "Lil' Slimfeat. PxMxWx"  the "feat." needs to be seperated.

Comment: Maybe the update gives now what you want?

Comment: Maybe the new update still gives what is expected but looks to be simpler than the previews one.

Comment: Hello @GKi I checked your code and tried in my main data file. I can say now it works around %95 accuracy. (There are some very difficult names to create a certain logic.) So I can say that works for me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to get artists:

```r
artist <- sub("^(?:.*?\\b(.+?)\\1(?=\\b|\\p{Lu}))*\\s*(.*)", "\\2", nlist, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "Where Your Ward At!!"   "Ms. Tee"                "Mister Wong"           
## => [4] "China Town"             "Teenage Girls"          "Electro Link 7"        
## => [7] "Thoughts Of Old Flames" "Chipero"
```

You may use the following code to get the titles:

```r
rx <- "^(?:.*?\\b(.+?)\\1(?=\\b|\\p{Lu}))*"
titles <- regmatches(nlist, regexpr(rx, nlist, perl=TRUE))
titles <- gsub("(.+?)\\1", "\\1", titles, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "Lil' Slim feat. PxMxWx"        
## => [2] "I Like It (Mannie Fresh Style)"
## => [3] "Bella Vista"                   
## => [4] "Tom Ware"                      
## => [5] "Race 'N Rhythm"                
## => [6] "Ronald Marquisse"              
## => [7] "Pleasure"                      
## => [8] "OM, Dom Um Romao"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7uX7o/3/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*?\b(.+?)\1(?=\b|\p{Lu}))*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(.+?)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `\1` - same value as in Group 1
  - `(?=\b|\p{Lu})` - next must be either a word boundary or an uppercase letter
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (`\2`): the rest of the line.

See the [**R demo online**](https://ideone.com/32DZQZ).

Comment: Thank you so much!
I just have the below error code. Do I miss a library?

```Error in regexpr(rx, nlist, perl = TRUE) : object 'rx' not found```

Comment: @podious No, you did not copy the `rx` variable definition.

Comment: @podious Take the code from https://ideone.com/32DZQZ

Comment: Thank you. But now I added a 9th row to "nlist". In this case the numbers are collapsed.

Comment: @podious Are you planning more "additions"? I will update the answer once you provide a complete set of requirements.

Comment: No. The list is long and I picked for you the only the problematic ones. But when I apply the rule you suggested I realized the correct ones are collapsed. This is why. If you want I can share the full list but I don't think you have time for it.

Comment: @podious Let me summerize: 1) if you follow your approach and remove duplicated parts first, you will lose the boundary between the artist and title, but 2) it is impossible to match the right duplicate parts as you might find duped single letters (as in `Tee`). Since my logic is looking for the last duplicated / repeated part, I need some boundaries to stick to. Your last `HookfaceHookface4 07 181221` example breaks any rule I can think of, making the pattern irregular. If you can formulate the context or char set to match in repeated parts, I can help further.

Comment: Thank you. I watched some tutorials and tried a bit. And tried to reconstruct what you did. Here is my suggestion I am not sure if it is possible.

(1) [Here](https://regex101.com/r/9jjMGq/1) I selected the "artist" names.
(2) The remain characters which  from the end of the string to matching token are "title". I am not sure if it is possible.
(3) Still remaining characters "feat." is the intermediate expression which needs to be placed into artist names. (If this is not possible we can skip that, it is not much necessary.)

Comment: @podious This logic explained in Point 2 won't work for `OM, Dom Um Romao`. I can get the `feat.` part, but working around the `OM, Dom Um Romao` would be hard.

Comment: This is the closest I could come to - [see R demo online](https://ideone.com/GjBgsL).